# jquery mobile data placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to make a multiple select menu by jQuery mobile, and I prefer native menu, so set data-native-menu="true".

When I set a data-placeholder text for the select menu, I found the data-placeholder can be selected.

Could I avoid data-placeholder to be selected?

By the way, my device is Samsung Galaxy S3.

Thanks.

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/HGBQc/62/

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyNNk.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://forum.jquery.com/topic/placeholder-in you can use placeholder only with data-native-menu="false".

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jquery mobile are you using?  If you're on 1.1.1 the you can try one of the following:

- Provide an option with no value attribute (or an empty value attribute)
- Provide an option with no text node
- Provide an option with a data-placeholder="true" attribute - so on the  tag as opposed to the . (This allows you to use an option that     has a value and a textnode as a placeholder option).

Jquery mobile automatically renders these as a menu heading instead of an option

Comment: I have tried all your suggestion, but it still not work. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HGBQc/66/

Comment: Hey, I've got your example to work...the issue is the version of jquery you are using.  Currently it is only compatible with jquery 1.6.4 or 1.7.1.  I believe the next version of Jquery Mobile (1.2) is going to be compatible with 1.7.2 & 1.8

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use jQuery 1.6.4 in jsFiddle, but the data-placeholder option is still selectable.